# Google App Engine: How to serve a static file from a RequestHandler?

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I have a `RequestHandler` which needs to send the contents of a large static file as a response. I could simply open the file and write it to the `response` object, but this is inefficient. Is there a way to hand off the delivery to the Google App Engine framework, similar to `send_blob`?

I could swear I've seen such a function before, but cannot find it again in the GAE documentation.

Comment: just return the path to it and let the client side fetch it

Comment: @ZigMandel You mean a redirect? This would introduce latency, and also change the URL. My handler is mapped to `/pets/my-cats`, but I'm trying to serve `/static/fr_FR/mes-chats.html`

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using a RequestHandler.  Instead, configure `app.yaml` for [Serving Static Files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/serving-static-files).  For example, to serve favicon.ico:

```
handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't do that, because I need to perform some logic to determine which static file will be served.

Comment: Is there any way you can perform the logic client-side?  For example, I have an AngularJS app that generates an image URL from the data.

Comment: My handler needs to choose the files based on a combination of the client's `Accept-Language` header and/or IP address, and serve locale-specific content.

Comment: Then I think writing to the Response object is your only solution.